# Where can I get better explanation of Cron Job Command?

Tags: linux, cron, command

I need 3 cronjob command that are,

```
1. A cronjob that will run every day at every 15 mins except Tuesday 5 PM to till Wednesday 2 AM. 
2. A Cronjob that will run every day at every 15 mins except Tuesday 11 PM to till Wednesday 3 AM. 
3. A Cronjob that will run every day at every 15 mins except Wednesday 9 AM to 10 AM.
```

I got some from online, but I am not understanding it. For no 3 I got this

`*/15 0-8,10-23 * * 0-2,4-6`

- The */15 means At every 15th minute
- The 0-8,10-23 means from 0-8 and
- 10-23 The * * means All day of the month and every month

`0-2,4-6` Here I am confused, 0-2 means Saturday,Sunday,Monday and 4-6 means Wednesday, Thursday, Friday.

My Confusion is Why Tuesday is not present here? And Isn't this means that on Saturday,Sunday,Monday,Wednesday, Thursday and Friday it won't run from 9-10?

Please share the proper cronjob expression and explain or suggest where I can get the cronjob expression.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: You can't do these with a single cron job. For #1 you need 3 jobs: Every day except Tuesday and Wednesday; Tuesday from midnight to 5pm; Wednesday from 2AM to midnight